# Namespaces in .net

Tags: .net, dll, .net-3.5, namespaces

I thought I knew the answer to this, but a compile error is telling me different.  I have created two separate libraries which contain the same stem namepsace; for example:

```
MyLib1.dll
```

contains

```
Common.MyFuncs.DoSomeStuff
```

And

```
MyLib2.dll
```

contains

```
Common.MyFuncs.DoOtherStuff
```

MyLib2.dll references myLib1.dll

When I include references to both in my project, MyLib1.dll is masking MyLib2.dll.  My question is simply, is this correct - i.e. is this what .net does?  I know it's possible to use extern for conflicting namepsaces, but I'm sure that I've seen namespaces shared across assemblies before (in fact, I'm sure that I've done it before), but I can't seem to find anything online to indicate I'm right or wrong.

Comment: You can use **aliases** (check properties page for each reference) to access _types_ in conflict (same name and same namespace from different DLLs). You can, for example, access `MyLib1.dll` types using `lib1::Common.MyFuncs` and `MyLib2.dll` types using `lib2::Common.MyFuncs`. By default they're all imported with the `global::` alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces don't "mask" each other, the same namespace can quite happily co-exist in multiple assemblies (in fact there are some System.* namespaces that exist across multiple assemblies). Are you sure that you don't have the same *types* defined in each assembly (maybe you've moved code but didn't rememove the original?), that way you won't get collisions between your types.

When you reference both projects, you still need to include a `using Common.MyFuncs.[whatever];` statement at the top of each code file that needs to use the types from it.

Comment: I was fully qualifying the types.  The problem turned out to be a VS2013 taking a funny turn.  After a restart it all sprung to life again.